# Is there a better way of determining empty associative arrays in php 5.3?

Tags: php

The empty() function in php 5.3 does not work well for associative arrays. I have an associative array that could have some 30+ elements.

```
$arr = array(
             'one'=>kwara, 
             'two'=>osun,
             ...
             'thirty'=>lagos
            )
```

If the associative array is empty like so:

```
$arr = array(
             'one'=>'', 
             'two'=>'',
             ...
             'thirty'=>''
            )
```

and I need to check if the array is empty, the following will not work in php 5.3.

```
if(empty($arr))
{
  echo "array is empty<br />>";
}
else
{
  echo "array is NOT empty<br />";
}
```

and will return 'array is NOT empty'. I am aware that the behaviour is different in [php 5.4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) but my current platform is php 5.3.

To overcome this problem, I have used the following:

```
if(strlen(implode('',array_values($arr))) > 0)       
{

 echo "array is NOT empty<br />>";
}
else
{
  echo "array is empty<br />";
}
```

**The question is**: is there a better of achieving this in php 5.3?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the PHP 5.4 change. `empty` never returns `true` for anything else but `array()`, i.e. a *really empty* array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No

Longer answer: The array you are looking at *is* not empty at all, it contains a bunch of keys with zero length strings. Your solution is probably one of the shortest possible *and* readable. You may want to wrap it in a function of your own though.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
if (sizeof(array_filter($array)) === 0) // do your stuff
```

Also you original could be improved like:

```
if (implode($array) !== '') // do your stuff
```

Comment: Just `if (array_filter($array))` will do too.

Comment: @deceze Triple `=` for clarity.

Comment: `array_filter()` will also remove `"key" => "0"`!

Comment: @phant0m likewise `empty("0")` is `true`, pass it a call back if you want to be more specific.

Comment: Sure, but that's irrelevant. It's just an important thing to be aware of, and the OPs example of an "empty array" has only empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Empty will work only with really empty values, your array has keys assigned so its not empty. Your solution is probably best way to do what you want - its hard to say, you would need to make some benchmarks, it can be done in many other ways:

```
if (array_filter($arr) === array()) {}
// or
if (!implode('', $arr)) {}
```

Comment: `> your array has keys assigned so its not empty.`
<<<<

And this is also true for PHP 5.4.x